# combine two variables in one loop laravel

Tags: laravel, loops

hello there i have two models one for questions and the other for the answers
i need to take all information from questions 
and from the answers 
then displaying each question and answers below each other

the problem is that they are in two diffrent tables so you have to store each of them in a variable 
now you have to variables 
when you try to display them by the for each loop they will repeat 
i need either i way to combine two varaibles into one 
or doing one for each loop accross two varaibales
i am using laravel by the way

controller

```
public function answerdquestions()


 {
    $Q = question::all();
    $A = answer::all();
    return view('guest.questions.answerd',compact('Q') , compact('A'));
  }
```

view

```
    extends('layouts.guest')
@section('questions')
@if(count($Q) == null)
<h1>no Answerd questions yet</h1>
@else
  @foreach($Q as $question)
    @if($question->answerd == 1)
    @foreach($A as $answer)
    <br>
    <div class="card" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 0, 
     0), rgb(67, 67, 67)); color:white;">
      <center><h3>{{$question->question}}</h3></center></div>
      <br>
      <div class="card">
        <center><h3>{{$answer->answer}}</h3></center>
      </div>
@endforeach

    @elseif($Q->answerd == 0)

    @endif
    @endforeach
    @endif
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a 1:1 relationship between question and answer and are they put in the same order? In this case, you should convert the collections in arrays using toArray() ( check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays) ) , then loop the arrays using a foreach by key and value. So you'd have

> @foreach($Q as $key => $question)

and then you'd get the answer using:

> $A[$key]->answer

But it would be better to use numeric identifier for questions and answers, and then retrieving the id by using question->id and using this to fetch the answer.

Comment: yes i just removed 1:1 relation I could just rewrite it 
but i didn't get what you mean by specifying the key

Comment: what i want to achieve here is like if they were in the same table and you wrote foreach($Q as $question) then you putted a dev and inside it 
{{$question->question}}
{{$question->answer}}

Comment: I meant, how do you identify to which question is the answer related? If you simply know it because they are in the same order in both tables, you can try with the solution I posted above (the one with key => $question and toArray() )

Comment: yeaaaaaaaah worked 100% thanks a lot i will post my code

Answer (score 0):

i quite tried all the ways for making a successfully 1:1 relationship and didn't work for me so i i made it manually by adding a column in the migration of the answer table which is 
question_id 
and then i went to the answer submitting form which is already has the question id passed in and i added an input with class hide and putted the value of it as $question->id

and then i just copied your soloution the loop with the key and worked just fine

admin store function

```
public function store_answer(Request $request , $id)
  {
    $this->validate($request,[
      'answer'=>'required',
    ]);
    $answer = new answer;
    $answer->answer = $request->input('answer');
    $answer->question_id = $request->input('question_id');
    $answer->save();
    return view('admin.questions.plus1', ['id' => $id]);
  }
```

admin submitting form

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')

<div>
  <h1>{{$question->question}}</h1>
</div>
<div>
  {!! Form::model($question,['method' => 'POST','action'=>['AdminQuestionsController@store_answer','id'=>$question->id,]]) !!}
  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('answer') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
    {{Form::label('Answer', 'Answer')}}
    {{Form::text('answer', '', ['class' => 'form-control required' , 'placeholder' => 'Enter your answer'])}}
  </div>
  {{Form::submit('submit',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::text('question_id', $question->id, ['class' => 'hide'])}}
  </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

guest view

```
@extends('layouts.guest')
@section('questions')
@if(count($Q) == null)
<h1>no Answerd questions yet</h1>
@else
@foreach($Q as $key => $question)
    @if($question->answerd == 1)
    <br>
    <div class="card" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(67, 67, 67)); color:white;">
      <center><h3>{{$question->question}}</h3></center></div>
      <br>
      <div class="card">
        <center><h3>{{$A[$key]->answer}}</h3></center>
      </div>

@elseif($Q->answerd == 0)

@endif
@endforeach
@endif
@endsection
```